# Firebase database losses synchronisation, when app is kept idle for a long time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have *setPersistance* enabled in my application to save data for offline. If the device is kept idle for a long time the app lost synchronization from the database and it is showing the date from the local database (already saved data).

In this case, the firebase User is not null

Firebase rule is like below

```
 "rules": 
        {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true"  
         }
```

Also, Network connectivity is active, pushing data to the database is not working too.

It just feel like the local database is completely detached from  the online database

Comment: Help will be appretiated

Comment: what you mean with
>  idle for a long time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OussemaAroua without use for a long time